# Symmetric relation with DAO pattern

Tags: java, jdbc, dao

I'm trying to implement the DAO pattern in Java but I am struggling to create a symmetric relation, for example, if I have a Teacher which has Students, I will create a List in the Teacher BUT should I create a Teacher property in the Student?

The DAO classes look like this:

```
public class TeacherDAO extends DAO<Teacher> {
    public Teacher find(int id) {
        Statement statement = Connection.getInstance();
        // Get the teacher and the students
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM teachers LEFT JOIN "
                                                + "students ON students.teacher_id = teacher.id")
        DAO<Student> studentDAO = new StudentDAO();

        Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
        teacher.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        teacher.setName(rs.getString("name"));

        List<Value> students = new ArrayList<>();
        rs.beforeFirst();
        // For each student, add it to the list (after hydratation)
        while (rs.next() && rs.getInt("student.teacher_id") == teacher.getId()) {
            students.add(studentDAO.find(rs.getInt("student.id")));
        }
        teacher.setstudents(students);

        return teacher;
    }

    public boolean update(Teacher t) {...}
    public boolean insert(Teacher t) {...}
    public boolean delete(Teacher t) {...}
}
```

No problem so far, BUT how the hell can I code the `find` of StudentDAO if a Student has a Teacher property? It would call the `find` of TeacherDAO and then loop infinitely.

But it's **necessary** that a Student has a Teacher property else how can I `insert` a new Student without specifying the corresponding Teacher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is also to handle this kind of problematic that [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) was created.

If you need a bidirectional relationship between Student and Teacher, you should indeed perform the relationship fetching a single time.

I note that in your example you want to load the Teacher but also its relationship.
That may be desirable in some cases but undesirable in other cases. So you should probably parameterize this feature.  I will detail this point soon.

In your case, i would probably define `findWithStudents(int teacherId)` in `TeacherDAO` that loads teachers and  delegates to `find(int studentId, Teacher teacher)` in `StudentDAO` to load a student.
In this way in `StudentDAO`, the method knows that the teacher was already loaded and it will not load it again.
If it makes sense as said you could have overload for some other cases.
For example `findWithTeacher(int studentId)` in `StudentDAO` that loads both the student and the teacher or `find(int teacherId)` in `TeacherDAO` that loads only the teacher.